# Submit radio buttons selection

Tags: javascript, ajax, radio-button, form-submit, getelementbyid

I have this code for a radio-button poll:

```
<div id="MyPoll">
How was the game?<br />
<form id="FirstPoll">
<input type="radio" name="Poll1" value="x" onclick="GetVote(this.value)" /> Awesome<br />
<input type="radio" name="Poll1" value="y" onclick="GetVote(this.value)" /> Awful<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

where the "GetVote" function is this:

```
function GetVote(int) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else  {
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("MyPoll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","PollResults.php?Poll1="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send(); }
```

In this way, when a user votes, the result directly shows, but I want the user vote to pass to a SUBMIT button before it shows.
I guess that I have to insert document.getElementById("FirstPoll").submit(); somewhere in my "GetVote" function (....where?), get rid of the 'onclick' events from the 'input' and trigger the "GetVote" function with a submit button?
Any suggestion is more than appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: Should probably use jQuery to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the submission from the `onsubmit` handler:

```
<form id="FirstPoll" onsubmit="GetVote(this); return false;">
    ...
</form>

function GetVote(form) {
    var int = form.Poll1.value;
    // Code to submit via AJAX
}
```